# Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Из-за чего возникает такая ошибка?
Установил убунту 19.04 и не устанавливаются некоторые пакеты как раньше.

```
sudo apt-get install ./dia_0.97.2-5_i386.deb


    Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
    Построение дерева зависимостей       
    Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
    Заметьте, вместо «./dia_0.97.2-5_i386.deb» выбирается «dia:i386»
    Некоторые пакеты не могут быть установлены. Возможно, то, что вы просите,
    неосуществимо, или же вы используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где
    запрошенные вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
    Следующая информация, возможно, вам поможет:

    Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
     dia:i386 : Зависит: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.13-4) но он не может быть установлен
                Зависит: dia-common:i386 (= 0.97.2-5) но он не может быть установлен
                Зависит: dia-libs:i386 (= 0.97.2-5) но он не может быть установлен
                Рекомендует: gsfonts-x11:i386 но он не может быть установлен
    E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.
```

Comment: А просто `sudo apt-get install dia` без всех этих странностей пробовали?

Comment: А тебе какие диаграммы надо рисовать?

Comment: Это не только в dia. 
Просто если ставить через snap менеджер приложений ubuntu то в программах разные глюки. А определенные версии определенных программ доступны только через deb пакеты.
Интересует почему говорит что "но он не может быть установлен".
Mongodb у меня не ставится и через sudo apt-get